# How to fetch ACL for Folders

Tags: c++, file, winapi, api, permissions

I work in C++, I need to fetch the ACLs for the folders in windows.
I am not sure about the APIs to be used to fetch it.
Does anyone know how to fetch the ACLs using windows API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GetKernelObjectSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by handle, [GetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by name.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/accessctrl1.aspx is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the API function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446639.aspx) from the platform sdk...

Answer (score 0):

See my sample code posted here, written in Win32 C++.

https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/win32acl/blob/master/win32acl.cpp